# Rename most recent image from IP cam and delete others

Tags: bash

I have no bash programming experience and a camera with crappy firmware.  I have completed the project I am trying to accomplish here:

http://www.computer-wiz.ca/snowmobile-test-page

- with a different camera with the correct firmware that uploads a picture to ftp and renames it, overwriting the previous picture and allowing me to display that picture on a webpage because it has the same name but it's updated from the last couple minutes.  This was my demo for a project I am currently working on, now with the same brand of camera, and an insufficient firmware that doesn't rename files.  Therefore I am left with a directory full of files, named as such:

```
Schedule_20141111_044312.jpg
Schedule_20141111_045312.jpg
```

As it uploads every 10 minutes.  My godaddy server only runs a cronjob twice an hour.  I need to:

- rename the most recent file in this folder to something constant that my webpage can display- ex: image.jpg
- move it to a folder called watermark where my php script can watermark it, and overwrite whatever file was there from the last move
- delete all the other pictures in the folder the camera uploads them to, so the server doesn't fill up

I realize this is a lot to ask and that third party software is out there, but I've already tried some and they slap branding all over the picture.  The current code I have is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd myhomedirectory/webcamuploads/FI9828W_00626E52FF8D/snap/
mv `ls -1t | head -1` myhomedirectory/html/webroot/webcamuploads/watermark/
```

It doesn't even like the header on this.  I keep getting files don't exist errors as well...

help?

Answer (score 2):

I would just successively move each file into place, letting newer files overwrite the older ones. Moving a file within a file system isn't expensive; it's just a change to directory entries, rather than actually copying the actual file from one place to another.

Since the files are sensibly named, the order is the same whether you sort lexicographically (which is what `Schedule_*.jpg` will do) or chronologically.

```
cd myhomedirectory/webcamuploads/FI9828W_00626E52FF8D/snap/
for f in Schedule_*.jpg; do
    mv "$f" myhomedirectory/html/webroot/webcamuploads/watermark/
done
```

There's no need to explicitly delete anything, since older files will simply be "overwritten" by newer files. After the loop completes, only the newest file remains.

Comment: Thanks alot for looking at my post, I have some errors and they are the same as the ones I was getting, it seems to not be able to find my file or directory, yet it finds the bash file, is this error common?

Comment: /var/chroot/home/content/53/11661053/html/webcamuploads/camerabash.sh: line 1: cd: /home/content/53/11661053/html/webcamuploads/FI9828W_00626E52FF8D/snap/
: No such file or directory
/var/chroot/home/content/53/11661053/html/webcamuploads/camerabash.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'
/var/chroot/home/content/53/11661053/html/webcamuploads/camerabash.sh: line 2: `for f in Schedule_*.jpg; do

Comment: It looks like your script might have DOS line endings; you can remove them with `dos2unix`.